# Testing with ef core in memory database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I am using ef core in project and my repository calls a stored procedure to get the results. I was wondering if I can use inMemorydatabase feature of ef core to test against my repository.

Comment: you can. Just set up your context with test Data and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can but you should not do it. From Microsoft:

> EF Core comes with an in-memory database that we use for internal
> testing of EF Core itself. This database is in general not suitable
> for testing applications that use EF Core. Specifically:
>
> - It is not a relational database.
> - It doesn't support transactions.
> - It cannot run raw SQL queries.
> - It is not optimized for performance.
>
> None of this is very important when testing EF Core internals because
> we use it specifically where the database is irrelevant to the test.
> On the other hand, these things tend to be very important when testing
> an application that uses EF Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database

Microsoft recommends using SQLite in-memory database instead. Always remember its lifetime though:

- The database is created when the connection to it is opened
- The database is deleted when the connection to it is closed

Sample:

```
public class SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest : ItemsControllerTest, IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbConnection _connection;

    public SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest()
        : base(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ItemsContext>()
                .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
                .Options)
    {
        _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(ContextOptions).Connection;
    }

    private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");

        connection.Open();
        
        return connection;
    }

    public void Dispose() => _connection.Dispose();
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite#using-sqlite-in-memory-databases